# Calculate and list how many different 4 digit numbers can be done with the numbers 0 to 9?

Tags: emeditor

There is something I want to learn.

Let's say we have some single digit numbers.

**Example:** `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0`
**Example II:** `1-2-4-6-0`

And with these numbers, we want to get `4-digit` numbers that are different from each other.
And we want to print them as lists.

**Result:**

- 4676
- 4236
- 1247
- 1236
- ....

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Please clarify `odd numbers`. In mathematics, odd numbers are 1, 3, 5, .... Please clarify input strings.

Comment: It's the single-digit numbers I'm talking about.
I updated the question and example.

Comment: How many combinations do you want to list? or do you want to list all combinations?

Comment: I want to list all combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write and run a macro like this:

```
// retrieve the selected text
str = document.selection.Text;

// check the input string format. The input must be something like: "1-2-4-6-0"
if( str.length == 0 ) {
    alert( "Select the input string" );
    Quit();
}
for( i = 0; i < str.length; ++i ) {
    c = str.substr( i, 1 );
    if( i % 2 == 0 ) {
        if( c < '0' || c > '9' ) {
            alert( "not digit" );
            Quit();
        }
    }
    else {
        if( c != '-' ) {
            alert( "not separated by '-'" );
            Quit();
        }
    }
}

var arr = new Array();
j = 0;
for( i = 0; i < str.length; ++i ) {
    if( i % 2 == 0 ) {
        c = str.substr( i, 1 );
        arr[j++] = c;
    }
}

if( arr.length < 4 ) {
    alert( "Input string should contain at least 4 digits" );
    Quit();
}

// list all 4-digit combinations
len = arr.length;
str = "";
for( i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
    for( j = 0; j < len; ++j ) {
        for( k = 0; k < len; ++k ) {
            for( l = 0; l < len; ++l ) {
                str += arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] + arr[l] + "\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

// write the list in a new document
editor.EnableTab = true;
editor.NewFile();
document.write( str );
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `GenCombinations.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run GenCombinations.jsee** in the **Macros** menu **after selecting an input string**.

Comment: I am getting a warning. [Warning](https://disk.yandex.com.tr/i/Sc_6P81jy3X5rg)

Comment: The input string must be selected before you run this macro, and only the input string of this format `1-2-3-4-...` without quotation marks must be selected.

Comment: I already tried this. But it didn't work. [Example](https://disk.yandex.com/i/vkBoDxicg6N3sw) There is no part in the macro that I need to edit, right?

Comment: Please try CTRL + A before running the macro.

Comment: You are life saver. Worked. Thank you.
Which part should I change to do this with the alphabet?

Comment: Change this part: `if( c < '0' || c > '9' ) {`